# Pandas rolling standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation

Is anyone else having trouble with the new `rolling.std()` in pandas?  The deprecated method was `rolling_std()`.  The new method runs fine but produces a constant number that does not roll with the time series.

Sample code is below.  If you trade stocks, you may recognize the formula for Bollinger bands.  The output I get from `rolling.std()` tracks the stock day by day and is obviously not rolling.

This in in pandas 0.19.1.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2012,12,31)
g = web.DataReader(['AAPL'], 'yahoo', start, end)
stocks = g['Close']
stocks['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stocks.index)
stocks['AAPL_LO'] = stocks['AAPL'] - stocks['AAPL'].rolling(20).std() * 2
stocks['AAPL_HI'] = stocks['AAPL'] + stocks['AAPL'].rolling(20).std() * 2
stocks.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you add the output you're actually expecting?

Comment: `stocks['AAPL'].rolling(20).std()` gives exactly the same output as `pd.rolling_std(stocks['AAPL'], window=20)`...

Comment: I can't reproduce here: it sounds as though you're saying `stocks['AAPL'].rolling(20).std()` is constant, but I see a non-constant time-varying result. For example, plotting, I see much thinner bands at around the July 2012 mark from those at around April 2012.

Comment: Thanks for showing std() is working correctly.  I had expected the 20-day lookback to be smoother, but it seems I will have to use mean() as well.

Answer (score 23):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import numpy as np
import datetime

end = datetime.date.today()
begin=end-pd.DateOffset(365*10)
st=begin.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ed=end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL",st,ed)

def bollinger_strat(data, window, no_of_std):
    rolling_mean = data['Close'].rolling(window).mean()
    rolling_std = data['Close'].rolling(window).std()

    df['Bollinger High'] = rolling_mean + (rolling_std * no_of_std)
    df['Bollinger Low'] = rolling_mean - (rolling_std * no_of_std)     

bollinger_strat(data,20,2)
```